# Removing "NaN" from a json list - Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a data frame that contains a column called identifiers and i need to change this to a json list.

> `list_identifiers=df['identifier'].tolist() listjson=json.dumps(list_identifiers)`

It looks like some Nan values are invalid and i get this error when i am running a query with the list.

```
DETAIL:  Token "NaN" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ...E00B8KQN827", "US0530151036", "CA82509L1076", NaN...
```

Can you help me remove the NaN from the json list? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share a sample data and the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json_list = json.dumps(df['identifier'].dropna().tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

For removing NAN from a list, did you try **numpy.nan** object?
I mean do it this way:

```
import numpy
list_identifiers = df['identifier'].tolist()
list_identifiers.remove(numpy.nan)
```

Furthermore, as I know there is also a **dropna** method in Pandas library you can use:

```
 list_identifiers = df['identifier'].dropna().tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas `to_json` should convert "NaN" to "null" for you, which are JSON compatible:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"identifiers": [1, 2, np.nan, pd.NA]})

df["identifiers"].to_json(orient="values")
# output: '[1,2,null,null]'
```